# Sending Probe Request Frames | Receving Probe Response -- Scapy

Tags: sniffer, python, routing, packet, 802.1x

**OBJECTIVE**

Send probe request frame `subtype=4` and receive probe response `subtype=5` with Scapy

Ultimate goal is to detect access points nearby via Scapy ( **not by sniffing beacon frames** )

The object of this is to learn how to initiate probe requests and collect the responses.

**ATTEMPTS**

POSSIBLE METHOD 1

*Wirelss card in Monitor mode*

*Broadcasting a probe request to anyone that can hear and recording response into variable immediately*

```
packet = RadioTap()/Dot11(type=0,subtype=4,addr1="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", addr2="00:11:22:33:44:55",addr3="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
response = sr(packet)
```

POSSIBLE METHOD 2

*Wireless card in Monitor mode*

*Broadcasting a probe request to anyone that can hear and then sniffing for response afterwards*

```
packet = RadioTap()/Dot11(type=0,subtype=4,addr1="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", addr2="00:11:22:33:44:55",addr3="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
sendp(packet)
packets = sniff(count=50, timeout=30)
```

**ISSUES**

Neither METHOD 1, nor METHOD 2 provided a successful result for me. I am quite unsure if I am going about this correctly. I have found so much documentation online for "sniffing out probe requests", but this is not what I want to do.

Comment: Did you put the correct interface for example sendp(packet,iface=card)
where card is your interface name in monitor mode(Double quotes)

Answer (score 2):

That's because you didn't include the "Dot11Elt" layer, try this:

```
RadioTap()/Dot11(type=0,subtype=4,addr1="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", addr2="00:11:22:33:44:55",addr3="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/Dot11Elt(ID="SSID", info="")
```

or:

```
RadioTap()/Dot11(addr1="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff",addr2="00:11:22:33:44:55",addr3="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/Dot11ProbeReq()/Dot11Elt(ID="SSID", info="")
```